# Has to be easy - Div panel text seems to realign center when clicking to collapse the panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

**The issue is at:** http://www.tenyeartwilight.com/

There is a jQuery slideToggle function on the second paragraph of the main section of the page (which is just a sandbox for me to learn). It works, but the enclosed text shifts from a left-align to a center-align and I can't figure out how and why, and I know this has got to be simple. The background corners change also, and I am not sure what's getting inherited/"de-herited".

I don't mind cruelty as long as I understand the solution.  Thanks.

p.s. - the text is an excerpt copied from *Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: MSBuild and Team Foundation Build* by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi and William Bartholomew.

EDIT: My web programming level should be pretty obvious from my question.  I understand the broad strokes, but am still breaking down the details.

Comment: could you add some code or even better a jsFiddle?

Comment: I suppose but you've already lost me with jsFiddle. Would just like to know what I mucked up in the css to get this unwanted text shift.  Thanks for replying tho

Comment: look at line 66 of your newindex.css, you have a margin of 50px on ul, li, try commenting that out once and see if that leads you to an answer. I cant tell without seeing your jQuery code edit: bgcorner2

Comment: jQuery is in the html of the page linked at top.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only centered when it collapse. It is centered all the time. The reason why it looks like its centered is because the second paragraph got covered by left menu.

when it collapse, jQuery set the width of the second paragraph to a right amount which is just wide enough to show the left side of the ul.

Add this css to your code to see what i mean.

```
#nav{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**EDIT:** Responsive css and restructure for better readability 
Move footer out of section. It's easier to manage and make scene to ours who read your code.So inside `<body>`you have

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="section"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

on the same level

Then in css you will have

```
#nav
{
    width: 18%;
    padding: 1%;
    float: left
}

#section
{
    width: 78%;
    padding: 1%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant!  Thank you Andy - I tried upvoting your response but I don't have 15 points or whatever yet.  That explains the corners also (like you say) which I had no idea as to why those would change when their dimensions are fixed.

Comment: EDIT: I should figure this out myself, but I tried setting the #section id to margin-left:250px; to begin at the right border of the #nav pane, but I guess that's not how it's done.  i'll take a hint? :)

Comment: I dont know if you are aiming for a responsive site. If yes, i would move the footer out of #section then make #section float right with a 80% width.

Comment: YES - responsive CSS, that is exactly what I am looking for. When the browser window gets resized, i don't want text running off the page and so forth.  The page looks just how I originally wanted it now (not content-wise, but in terms of getting the layout right). I just went through a couple w3 tutorials.  I will google the tenants of responsive CSS - do you have any good links to offer?  Again, thank you very much.   EDIT: I'm not too concerned with the footer for now, I understand it would look better if it matched the header properties..

Comment: @user1701299 Bootstrap is a very good one. And you can find tons of tutorials and guidelines for it